# ImageView As Button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Below Code:

```
[View setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[View addTarget:self action:@selector(GoButton:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)GoButton:(id)sender

{

NSLog(@"pressed");

}
```

Comment: view as your image view,

Comment: elaborate more ... this is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u need a click action for an image, y dont u use a button with image instead?

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btnOne setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

> UIImageView is not a control, you can't add a target for control events to it

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];
    [imageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [imageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Then call your gesture method like this :

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Button with a image as following:

```
UIButton *button  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Hope it helps..